# How do I filter specific rows in a csv file based on two conditions? (using pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, conditional-statements

My dataframe basically looks like this: (where df=pd.read_csv(csv_file_name))

```
    'Acid'  'Ion'  'File Name'    'Area'
0    'Cholic' '390'  'sth-E-1.raw'  '594'
1    'Cholic' '392'  'sth-E-2.raw'  '630'
2    'Cholic' '388'  'sth-E-3.raw'  '710'
3    'Cholic' '330'  'sth-E-1.raw'  '700'
4    'Cholic' '340'  'sth-E-2.raw'  '690'
5    '7alpha' '729'  'sth-E-1.raw'  '109'
6    '7alpha' '745'  'sth-E-1.raw'  '115
```

I want to print only the rows which contain 'Cholic' as a Name and contain the 'E-1.raw' in the File Name

So far, I 've only thought of doing a print statement like this:

```
print(df[(df['Acid'] == 'Cholic') & ('E-1.raw' in df['File Name']))
```

Comment: And what is your problem/question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need -

```
df[(df['Acid'] == 'Cholic') & (df['File Name'].str.contains('E-1.raw')]
```

**Output**

```
     Acid  Ion    File_Name  Area
0  Cholic  390  sth-E-1.raw   594
3  Cholic  330  sth-E-1.raw   700
```

**Explanation**

The problem with your code is in this condition specifically -

```
'E-1.raw' in df['File Name']
```

This returns one truthy value whether the string `'E-1.raw'` is present in the full series `df['File Name']`. It will only produce one `True/False` value which is not what you want.

You want to filter out *each* string in `df['File Name']` whether it contains the `'E-1.raw'` on a row by row basis, which you do by casting your series as a `str` first and then use the `contains` function.

Comment: Thank you!! i've been trying to figure this out for like 3 hours

Comment: I actually get an error. python highlights the single parenthesis after 'contains' as an error. Im not sure what the problem is here....

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan

Comment: @LuisOng yes there was a typo. Modified ans

Comment: @VivekKalyanara

Comment: How would I do this if i wanted to put an 'if' condition. As such:

Comment: if df[(df['Acid'] == 'Cholic') & (df['File Name'].str.contains('E-1.raw')]:           print(row)